# asp.net controls value not pass to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My Question is :  asp.net controls value not pass to javascript function

**Asp.Net Code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsubcategorycodeid" class="form-control " runat="server" placeholder="Sub Category Code ID"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsubcategoryname" class="form-control " runat="server" Height="25px" placeholder="Sub CategoryName In Letter"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddcategorycodeid" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>---Select---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddstatus" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>---Select---</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Active</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>In-Active</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return btnSave3_onclick()" />
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var txtsubcategorycodeid = $("#txtsubcategorycodeid").val();
var txtsubcategoryname = $("#txtsubcategoryname").val();
var ddcategorycodeid = $("#ddcategorycodeid").val();
var ddstatus = $("#ddstatus").val();
```

When I call it it display Undefined

This Code Work in Simple Form, But not work with integration on template and I put this code to integrated Template.
        It will Not Work.

```
    This Asp.Net Code in content placeholder. 
    If I use input html control then its works.
```

Comment: Try with [Control.ClientId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) i.e. `$("#<%= txtsubcategorycodeid.ClientID %>").val()`

Comment: Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your aspx control.

Comment: This Code I try but its not working.

Comment: ClientIDMode="Static" this code is working

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version ASP.NET 4 or greater then you can add `ClientIDMode` attribute to your controls which will not change your ids like this:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsubcategorycodeid" class="form-control " runat="server" 
     placeholder="Sub Category Code ID" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

In this case you will get the correct result if you execute this:-

```
var txtsubcategorycodeid = $("#txtsubcategorycodeid").val();
```

If you have a lower version of ASP.NET (<4) the you can use the `ClientID` property to fetch the actual ID being rendered like this:-

```
var txtsubcategorycodeid = $("#<%= txtsubcategorycodeid.ClientID %>").val();
```